# Why Refresh in Impala in required if invalidate metadata can do same thing

Tags: impala

Using Hive if I create one table,insert records in it and to reflect the same table in Impala first I have to run Invalidate Metadata which reflects the metadata on the executor also shows newly added records as well.
Then my question is still why we need to do the refresh table?

Answer (score 0):

`INVALIDATE METADATA` and `REFRESH` are counterparts:

- `INVALIDATE METADATA` is an asynchronous operations that simply
  discards the loaded metadata from the catalog and coordinator caches.
  After that operation, the catalog and all the Impala coordinators
  only know about the existence of databases and tables and nothing
  more. Metadata loading for tables is triggered by any subsequent
  queries.
- `REFRESH` reloads the metadata synchronously. `REFRESH` is more
  lightweight than doing a full metadata load after a table has been
  invalidated. `REFRESH` cannot detect changes in block locations (as `INVALIDATE METADATA` does) triggered by operations like HDFS balancer, hence causing remote
  reads during query execution with negative performance implications.

  Use `REFRESH` after invalidating a specific table to separate the
  metadata load from the first query that's run against that table.

====

`INVALIDATE METADATA` is required when the following changes are made outside of Impala, in Hive and other Hive client, such as SparkSQL:

- Metadata of existing tables changes.
- New tables are added, and Impala will use the tables.
- The SERVER or DATABASE level Sentry privileges are changed from
  outside of Impala.
- Block metadata changes, but the files remain the same (HDFS
  rebalance). UDF jars change.
- Some tables are no longer queried, and you want to remove their
  metadata from the catalog and coordinator caches to reduce memory
  requirements.

No `INVALIDATE METADATA` is needed when the changes are made by impalad.

For even more details, read [HERE](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html)